# Choose the current month

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a check box with value for month I want to check the current month.

```js
var d = new Date(),

  n = d.getMonth(),

  y = d.getFullYear();
console.log(n);
$("input[name='month[]']").each(function() {
  $(this).val().split("_");
  console.log($(this).val().split("-")[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="checklist">
  <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input type="checkbox" value="April-2020" name="month[]" id="month_April_2020"><label for="month_April_2020" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">April-2020</label></li>
  <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input type="checkbox" value="May-2020" name="month[]" id="month_May_2020"><label for="month_May_2020" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">May-2020</label></li>
  <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input type="checkbox" value="June-2020" name="month[]" id="month_June_2020"><label for="month_June_2020" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">June-2020</label></li>
</ul>
```

I want to checked the 'May 2020' based on current year last month.

Comment: What is your problem here?

Comment: I got a number for month

Comment: Maybe you should change the id to the checboxes like: when is April something like `id=month_3` (3 because i think Date gives numbers between 0-11) Then you can just compare actual month with the id month_ + `actualMonth`

Comment: Its a dynamic filter

Comment: You need to create an Array/Object that maps the months names to their indices, then it's trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a map of the months' indices to their names, then it's simple to identify the previous month, given its index:

```js
const monthsNames = ['January', 'February', 'Match', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

var d = new Date(),
  n = d.getMonth(),
  y = d.getFullYear();

const previousMonthName = monthsNames[n-1];

$("input[name='month[]']").each(function() {
  const monthName = $(this).val().split("-")[0];
  if (monthName === previousMonthName) {
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="checklist">
  <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input type="checkbox" value="April-2020" name="month[]" id="month_April_2020"><label for="month_April_2020" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">April-2020</label></li>
  <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input type="checkbox" value="May-2020" name="month[]" id="month_May_2020"><label for="month_May_2020" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">May-2020</label></li>
  <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input type="checkbox" value="June-2020" name="month[]" id="month_June_2020"><label for="month_June_2020" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">June-2020</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could update the `ids` of the checkboxes to the matching index of a month and do the following:

```js
const date = new Date();
const monthIndex = date.getMonth();
const year = date.getFullYear();
$(`#${monthIndex}`).prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="checklist">
  <input type="checkbox" value="April-2020" id="3"><label>April-2020</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="May-2020"><label>May-2020</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="June-2020" id="5"><label>June-2020</label>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare current with your value and set checked as

```
if(month == currentMonth){
       $(this).attr('checked', 'checked')
}
```

```js
var d = new Date(),

  n = d.getMonth(),

  y = d.getFullYear();
console.log(n);
$("input[name='month[]']").each(function() {
  $(this).val().split("_");
  var month = $(this).val().split("-")[0];
  var currentMonth = getMonth(new Date());
  //alert(month);
  if(month == currentMonth){
       $(this).attr('checked', 'checked')
  }
});

function getMonth(d){
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
return month[d.getMonth()];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="checklist">
  <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input type="checkbox" value="April-2020" name="month[]" id="month_April_2020"><label for="month_April_2020" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">April-2020</label></li>
  <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input type="checkbox" value="May-2020" name="month[]" id="month_May_2020"><label for="month_May_2020" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">May-2020</label></li>
  <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input type="checkbox" value="June-2020" name="month[]" id="month_June_2020"><label for="month_June_2020" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">June-2020</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```js
var d = new Date(),
    n = d.getMonth(),
    y = d.getFullYear();
    
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";

var currentDate = month[n] + '-' + y;

$("input[name='month[]']").each(function() {
  $(this).val().split("_");
  console.log($(this).val().split("-")[0]);
});

$(`input[type=checkbox][value=${currentDate}]`).prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="checklist">
  <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input type="checkbox" value="April-2020" name="month[]" id="month_April_2020"><label for="month_April_2020" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">April-2020</label></li>
  <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input type="checkbox" value="May-2020" name="month[]" id="month_May_2020"><label for="month_May_2020" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">May-2020</label></li>
  <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input type="checkbox" value="June-2020" name="month[]" id="month_June_2020"><label for="month_June_2020" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">June-2020</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the current date, then set a new date with the last month, next get month name using ECMAScript International API

Then check which month is the most recent month

```
var d = new Date(),
newDate = new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1)),
    
lastMonth = newDate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });

$("input[name='month[]']").on('change', function()
{
    $(this).filter(':checked').each(function(){
       $(this).val().split("_")[0];
       console.log($(this).val().split("-")[0]);
       if ($(this).val().split("-")[0] == lastMonth )
       {
           console.log(`${$(this).val().split("-")[0]} is the last month`);
       }
    });
});
```